# repeat starting from a date defined javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a script, which should increase the date by one day partenda from a defined.
here is the code

```js
var data_inizio ="25/05/2016";
var turni = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var n_g_mesi = ["31","28","31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31"];

//Costruiso la data nel formato preferito
    var data = new Date();
    var aaaa, mm, gg;
    gg = data.getDate();
    mm = data.getMonth()+1;
    aaaa = data.getFullYear();
 n_g_q_mese =  n_g_mesi[ data.getMonth()]; // numeri di giorni in un mese

var numero_turni = 7;
var n = turni.length;

for(var i=0;i<numero_turni;i++) {

        $('#ul').append('<li>'+ data_inizio+' '+ turni[i%n]+"<br />\n" +'</li>');

        var gg = gg%n_g_q_mese+1;



    if(gg==1){
        mm = mm%12+1;
        if(mm==3 && aa%4==0 && n_g_q_mese==28){ // se l'anno è bisestile
            mm = 2;
            gg = n_g_q_mese = 29;
        }else{
            n_g_q_mese = n_g_mesi[mm];
            if(mm==1)
                aa++;
        }
    }





        var data_inizio = gg+"/"+mm+"/"+aaaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

The script does not detect my start date 25/05/2016, but considers the current one. Where am I wrong? can you help me

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem is that you've done

```
var data = new Date();
```

...and not in any way used your `data_inizio`. When you do that, it defaults to the current date.

Instead, use the `Date` constructor that accepts year, month, day (and optional time info). Note that when you do, the month value starts with 0, so:

```
var data = new Date(2016, 4, 25); // 25/05/2016 because months start with zero
```

But the rest of the code is working **much** harder than necessary and is implementing the algorithm for leap years incorrectly. Fortunately, you don't have to do that at all, `Date` will happily do it for you if you just increase the day by one:

```
data.setDate(data.getDate() + 1);
```

It handles wrapping to the next month (and year) automatically.

So if I'm reading the rest of that code correctly:

```js
var turni = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var data = new Date(2016, 4, 25); // "25/05/2016"
var numero_turni = 7;
var n = turni.length;
for (var i = 0; i < numero_turni; i++) {
  $("#ul").append(
    "<li>" +
    formatDate(data) +
    ' '+ turni[i%n] +
    "<br />\n" +
    "</li>");
  data.setDate(data.getDate() + 1);
}

function formatDate(dt) {
  var g = String(dt.getDate());
  var m = String(dt.getMonth() + 1);
  var a = String(dt.getFullYear());
  if (g.length == 1) {
    g = "0" + g;
  }
  if (m.length == 1) {
    m = "0" + m;
  }
  return g + "/" + m + "/" + a;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul"></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help and code correction. But I need a clarification.
You wrote var date = new Date (2016, 4, 25); // "05/25/2016" but how can I if the 05/25/2016 date is taken from a db? You need to break it down and then pass it to a date variable?

Comment: @Sixdas: You'll need to parse the string (pretty easy: `var parts = theString.split("/")`) and then use the `new Date(years, months, days)` constructor (remember to convert the strintgs in `parts` to numbers, and take one off the months value).

Comment: ok thanks, I eventually did so, I hope it is the best method.                          var data_start = "25/05/2016";
var split = data_start.split('/');
var days  = split[0];
var months = split[1]-1;
var years = split[2];

var data = new Date(years, months, days); // "25/05/2016"

Comment: @Sixdas: That's fine, but FWIW I'd add `+` in front of `parts[0]` and `parts[2]` to make them numbers. (The `- 1` after `parts[1]` makes it a number.)

Answer (score 0):

From here

`var data = new Date();
    var aaaa, mm, gg;
    gg = data.getDate();
    mm = data.getMonth()+1;
    aaaa = data.getFullYear();`

You get dates from current date and not using data_inizio at all. Just to print in first LI element.

Calculate that values from your initial date and all should be OK.

Hope this helps.